# Ajax form submit laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, laravel

Goodevening,

I am trying to make a POST request using ajax and the laravel framework. Im still learning laravel, php and now Ajax. I followed a tutuorial and a few questions here yet i am still kind of confused on the matter. I have a form i want to submit with interests a user can choose with checkboxes. Each checkbox has a value which represents the interest a user can follow to recieve articles. My table is structured with columns (user_id)=interest and (follower_id)=(id of current user). So that when a user clicks a checkbox, it will submit a new row with their id and the id of the interest.My issue is how to submit this information. At first i wanted to use one form that can submit/make multiple rows, but couldnt find a solution for that. Then i read that i can make multiple forms and submit them with Ajax. which i'm having trouble with currently i get this error 500 (Internal Server Error). Can someone help explain where i went wrong? Here is my code.....

HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(array('id'=> 'form1')) !!}
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::checkbox('interest_id', '1', true, ['class' => 'formclick submit']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                {!! Form::open(array('id'=> 'form2')) !!}
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::label('title','Title:', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::checkbox('interest_id', '2', true, ['class' => 'formclick submit']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <input id = "submit_me" type="button" value="Click Me!"  />
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

var interest_id = $('.formclick');

$('.submit').click(function(){
    var interest = {
        user_id: interest_id.val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/interest',
        data: interest,
        success: function() {
           alert('new interest');
        }
    });
});
```

InterestController:

```
    public function store(InterestRequest $interest)
{
    $interest = new Follower(array(
        'user_id' => $interest->get('interest_id'),
        'follower_id'  => Auth::id()
    ));

    $interest->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some change in InterestController

```
'user_id' => $interest->input('user_id'),
```